# How to Click a List Item Where Title Attribute Equals a Specific Variable Using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, click, title

I've got the following lists in my web application:

```
<li class="ui-corner-all" title="#3100ff" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(144, 0, 255);"></li>
<li class="ui-corner-all" title="#9330ff" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(144, 0, 255);"></li>
<li class="ui-corner-all" title="#500055" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(144, 0, 255);"></li>
```

Basically, I am trying to get JS and/or JQuery to click the list item with a specific title value. For example, click the list-item with the title attribute value of `#9330ff`.

I'm looking for code that is something like this:

```
          var colortxt = '#9330ff';
     if ($("li.ui-corner-all").attr("title") = colortxt) {

        $("li.ui-corner-all[title=colortxt]").click();

        }
```

This code does not work.

Does anyone know any code that is similar to this that would serve this particular function? If so, could you please say what this is?

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** if I use `$("li.ui-corner-all[title='#9330ff']").click();`, it clicks the list-item. However, when I use the code shown above (using the if statement and the `colortxt` variable), it will not click the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), As the value of title contains `#` in selector which needs to be escaped so we enclosed it with single quotes

```
$("li.ui-corner-all[title='#9330ff']").click(function() {
   alert(this.title);
});
```

**Edit** based on comments as OP want to click when item with particular attribute exits.

```
$("li.ui-corner-all[title='#9330ff']").click(function () {
    alert(this.title);
});
var colortxt = '#9330ff';
var liObj = $("li.ui-corner-all[title='" + colortxt + "']");
if(liObj.length)
   liObj.click();
```

Comment: My friend, I want the javascript to click it for me. I don't want the user to click the list. For example, if var green = 'green' and the title of a list item is green, then I want that list item to be .click() by javascript/jquery.

Comment: You can use $("li.ui-corner-all[title='#9330ff']").click();

Comment: Could you please see the updated code in my question?

Comment: Or just tell me how to use $("li.ui-corner-all[title='#9330ff']").click();  with a variable instead of a color (e.g. $("li.ui-corner-all[title=VARIABLE]").click();

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example, http://jsfiddle.net/aec8v3c8/

```
var li = $('li[title="#9330ff"]').on('click', function(){
    alert("yay you clicked me");
});

li.click(); // call click() to fire the event handler.
```

Comment: My friend, I want the javascript to click it for me. I don't want the user to click the list-item. For example, if var green = 'green' and the title of a list item is green, then I want that list item to be .click() by javascript/jquery.

Comment: Could you please see the updated code in my question?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you notice that you have a couple of syntax errors here

```
if ($("li.ui-corner-all").attr("title") = colortxt) {
```

here is a problem with the comparision operator, it has to be ===

```
if ($("li.ui-corner-all").attr("title") === colortxt) {
```

The other one is with the selector

```
$("li.ui-corner-all[title=colortxt]").click();
```

This is a bad string concatenation, you have to concatenate the var in the following way

```
$("li.ui-corner-all[title='" + colortxt + "']").click();
```

i hope this can help you